# Set all Labels to the same Font, Size, Border, etc in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, fonts, global

Is it possible to set the font property to affect all  tags, and nothing else on a single aspx page?

I have about 40 Labels throughout my page that all look the same as this, with varying IDs of course ...

```
<asp:Label ID="lblIDn" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("somecolumn" ) %>' Backcolor="White" BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="30" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
```

I don't want to have to change all 40 labels one by one. Is there a way to set them all like this, using CSS perhaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (Control item in form1.Controls)
{
    try { 
        ((Label)item).BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Azure; 
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Only labels are changed.

If you want check selected label you can use:

```
if( item.UniqueID == "lblIDn")
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping for an answer without codebehind and it seems CSS is the only way to go. Would you know what CSS I should use? I am new to CSS. Thanks